# Spreadsheet event trigger on Google Apps script doesn't fire when the sheet is edited by another script

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I wrote a small script bound to a Google spreadsheet that reads an email-address from a cell in the last row and sends an email to it.
The values are collected by a WebApp (not by Google form).

I tried all kind of triggers. The time driven triggers work, but the spreadsheet triggers don't work. I tried all of them. If I change manually some cell in the spreadsheet the onEdit trigger is working, but it doesn't fire up when the sheet was changed by another script.

Comment: You could duplicate the `onEdit()` code in the web app, and run it from the web app.

Answer (score 0):

Google's dev says : The onEdit() trigger runs automatically when a user changes the value of any cell in a spreadsheet. but it doesn't precise the change could be from script or not.

You'll find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177990/google-apps-script-createevent-function-not-creating-calendar-event) a comment from HDCerberus :

I'm not at my PC to write a full response, but at a glance it could be the OnEdit trigger, which ONLY works when the sheet is edited manually, and NOT by a script. Are you expecting it to run when the sheet is edited manually or by a script?

Answer (score -1):

Not every change triggers onEdit(). Please take a look on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15234631/3671473) from topic [Detect user inserting row or column in a google spreadsheet and reacting in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232405/detect-user-inserting-row-or-column-in-a-google-spreadsheet-and-reacting-in-a-sc) - you will find registered bugs and one of them says that values written by scripts do not trigger onEdit().